# program in C launches correctly but printf doesnt show anything

Tags: c

I run the programm and the console appears but printf doesnt print anything,
how can I fix this?

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    float fa;
    int cel;
    cel=0;
    while(cel<=200);
    {
        fa=9.000*(cel+32.000)/5.000;
        printf("%d\t%.3f\n",cel,fa);
        cel=cel+20;
    }
}
```

In addition I have a very similar program that runs correctly

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
  float celsius;
  int fahr;
  fahr = 0;
    while(fahr<=100){
    celsius=5.0000*(fahr-32.0000)/9.0000;
    printf("%d\t%.4f\n",fahr,celsius);
    fahr=fahr+1;
  }
}
```

I ran both programs in c-free 5

Answer (score 9):

Infinite loop:

```
while(cel<=200);
```

because of trailing `;` it is equivalent to:

```
while(cel<=200) {}
```

which means the `printf()` is never reached and `cel` is never modified. Remove the `;` to correct.

Answer (score 1):

Please remove semicolon after while

```
while(cel<=200)
```

Correct code is :

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    float fa;
    int cel;
    cel=0;
    while(cel<=200) // semicolon removed here
    {
        fa=9.000*(cel+32.000)/5.000;
        printf("%d\t%.3f\n",cel,fa);
        cel=cel+20;
    }
}
```